# jQuery fire function when element specific class change

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-events

I need to trigger an event when i add a specific class on button, but I have no idea how to make it listen to the class adding event.

I have something like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">   

$(document).ready(function() {
 

    $(id_element).addClass("active");
 
     //this function will fire on add "active" class to "id_button" element
     function fireOnActiveClass() {
        //do something
     }


} 

</script>
```

I can't touch code `$(id_element).addClass("active");`, for more reasons.

Currently I use jQuery 1.7.2

Could you please tell me how or which I need to know?

Comment: [Mutation Observer](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver)?

Comment: There are many different ways to do that but the question would be why you need that regarding your posted code because obviously you already know **when** you add this specific class

Comment: If you don't need to support older browsers, you could use animation/transition end event using fake animation/transition and using specific CSS rule. Or extend `addClass()` method to trigger custom event, or...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found solution using this jQuery Plugin: http://meetselva.github.io/attrchange/

Answer (score 1):

You are modifying the class of the control in your code. So why not simply call the click of the button when you change the class ?

```
$(id_element).addClass("active");
$(id_button).click();

$(id_button).click(function () {
     if ($(this).hasClass) {
     //do something

     }
 });
```

Answer (score 1):

There is no event raised when a class changes. The alternative is to manually raise an event when you programatically change the class:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(id_element).addClass("active").trigger('classChange');
    $(id_element).on('classChange', function() {
         // do stuff
    });
});
```

Comment: Why would you need to trigger a custom event here? Just call method once class is added

Comment: @A.Wolff Triggering a custom event offers more flexibility and allows one to listen to event bubbling, perhaps? It is also more extensible.

Comment: But as you still need to trigger it, I don't see any purpose here (regarding this concrete example)  PS: ya regarding flexibility and maybe bubbling

Answer (score 0):

One other way would be to call a function right after adding the class like:

```
$.fn.classAdded = function() {
    var $button = $(this);
    if($button.hasClass('id_button')) {
        // ...
    }
    return $button;
}

$(id_element).addClass("active").classAdded();
```

Answer (score 0):

Could this jQuery plugin be any help?

https://github.com/tormjens/jquery-dom-router

You can change the default element using
`$.DOMRouter.defaults.element = '#element';`
before initalizing the plugin.